# Why does Grover's algorithm behaves so different for different solution addresses?

Tags: ibm-q-experience

Attached please find two circuits for the IBM quantum composer, that show the outcome of Grover's algorithm with 3 QuBits after 2 iterations for the situation, where the solution is at address 111 and for the situation, where the solution is at address 101.

I am astonished, that the probabilities differ so much.

Is that possible, that finding the solution at 111 is so much clearly than finding the solution at 101 ?[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a missing CNOT gate from your oracle. It should be:

[image]

And the whole circuit should be:

[image]

This is because you want to add a phase when the state is $|101\rangle$. The first CNOT will change this state to $|111\rangle$ so you can apply the same oracle used in your other circuit. Then apply CNOT again to undo the effect of the first CNOT.

Comment: Wow ! You are right ! That works ! Thank you so much !

Comment: Dear Egretta.Thula: When I run this circuit on the IBM composer, then after one oracle and one reflection I get the following result:
0.177  0.177  0.177  0.177  0.177  0.884  0.177  0.177
but all state vectors are painted in red, so that means negative amplitude, right ?
However, they should all be positive. What am I missing here ?